# Android WebChromeClient with nanvigation

Tags: android, webview, android-4.4-kitkat

I am trying to create an app that has a Webview to view a site (with full navigation). The problem is the site requires Chrome. I tried setting the user-agent but that did not work.

In order to get around this I used

`webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient(){});`

This was able to bypass the sites browser check.

The problem I have now is I cannot seem to navigate the site without it opening the default browser app.

I tried using the WebChromeClients `onRecievedTitle` method but with no success.

Is this even possible? If so, can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: can you give the website link?

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot.